# extracting number from character array

Tags: kdb, q-lang

How do you extract numbers from a particular column composed of strings
eg:

```
(`category:"abc 124M def 154M" ; "hij 120M hij 174M" ; "stu 126M def 166M" ; "abx 67M def 66M" )
```

Answer:

```
124,154 
120,174
126,166
67,66
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site.

Answer (score 3):

There might be more efficient answers out there, but this works:

```
q)f:{except[;0Nj]"J"$" "vs?[x in "0123456789";x;" "]}
q)category
"abc 124M def 154M"
"hij 120M hij 174M"
"stu 126M def 166M"
"abx 67M def 66M"
q)f each category
124 154
120 174
126 166
67  66
```

Answer (score 0):

See 'inter'

```
q)myStrings:("he11o";"I am a p3rs0n")
q)myStrings inter\:.Q.n
"11"
"30"
q)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, fixing up the syntax can give us the table:

```
show tab:([]category:("abc 124M def 154M" ; "hij 120M hij 174M" ; "stu 126M def 166M" ; "abx 67M def 66M"))
category
-------------------
"abc 124M def 154M"
"hij 120M hij 174M"
"stu 126M def 166M"
"abx 67M def 66M"
```

From here we can only include numeric chars and spaces with `inter`, splitting on spaces and converting to get the numbers, excluding null values.

```
q){r@'where each not null r:"J"$" "vs/:x inter\:.Q.n," "}tab`category
124 154
120 174
126 166
67  66
```